# PHP Contact Form misses submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Would a Wordpress contact form7 misses any submission? My client was using it for a reservation form to different outlets but he somehow complained to me that he did not receive some of the clients reservation submission.

I'm thinking maybe the form would misses when there's a few senders who click submit form at the same time. How would I be able to modify it? Would I be able to trace those left out emails? I only have basic knowledge on PHP.

Comment: How are you storing submissions? MySQL / Email

Comment: Right now they aren't using any but I'm thinking to store them in database.

Comment: So possible reasons are: Request didn't complete from client. Email SMTP failed to send email.